# Weird issue with Member Initializers C++

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm making a game with C++ and SDL2. I have a class called "text" and a class called "buttonObj"

The constructor of "text" is a void function that takes an SDL_Color variable.

The first part of buttonObj looks like this:

```
string textContent;
text buttonText;
text highlighted_buttonText;

//Constructor
buttonObj(string tex, SDL_Color notHighlighted, SDL_Color highlighted) : 
  textContent( tex ), 
  buttonBase( img ), 
  buttonText( notHighlighted ), 
  highlighted_buttonBase( hI ), 
  highlighted_buttonText( highlighted )
{}
```

Currently, this works, but I don't exactly know WHY it works. With a constructor initializer, the value outside the parenthesis gets assigned to the value within the parenthesis. So, how come an SDL_Color (i.e "notHighlighted") can get assigned to a text variable? (i.e buttonText)

I assume this is because with a class, the variable inside the parenthesis is a parameter of the constructor of that class. So, since the constructor of text takes an SDL_Color variable, the program treats "notHighlighted" as a parameter, rather than the regular one-line initializer. Right?

Speculation Aside, this works. From my console, I can see **two "text" instances are constructed**, one for "highlighted" and one for "notHighlighted". **Once the texts are constructed, they remain as they should and render as they should later on in the code.**

However, this isn't what I want... Instead of passing an SDL_Color into the constructor and having buttonObj turn the color into text, (via constructing it)  I want to load some text beforehand (elsewhere during runtime) and pass the text into buttonObj directly. Like so:

```
string textContent;
text buttonText;
text highlighted_buttonText;

//Constructor
buttonObj(string tex, text notHighlighted, text highlighted) : 
  textContent( tex ), 
  buttonBase( img ), 
  buttonText( notHighlighted ), 
  highlighted_buttonBase( hI ), 
  highlighted_buttonText( highlighted )
{}
```

According to my knowledge of what one line initializers are SUPPOSED to do, "highlighted_buttonText" should become equal to the parameter "highlighted." So "highlighted_buttonText" is set to whatever the parameter "highlighted" is, **since they're both of type "text"**

However, this doesn't work. In my console, I see that the texts are constructed and then destructed! As if something is calling the destructor... this means that the variables don't work fine later on in the code. (And then I get a bunch of exceptions in the library I'm using for text rendering. It's a text chaching library based on SDL_TTF called SDL_FontCache)

I know this is a hard issue to explain and I might not be describing it well. But please, any advice would be awesome! Weird problems like this irk me...

Answer (score 2):

With your first chunk of code, you use the *initializer list* to *construct* the class variables. So in this case, a *copy* of `notHighlighted` is passed to the constructor of `buttonText` during the construction of the instance of `buttonObj`. The values are not *assigned*, they're *copied*. For trivial objects like SDL_Color, it's not really an issue.

In your second code chunk, you get stuff deleted because the *copy constructor* of `buttonText` is called to construct `buttonText` from `notHighlighted`. Once the copy is done (i.e. once `buttonText` is constructed from `notHightlighted`), the copy (which is notHighlighted) is deleted (i.e. the destructor is called). If `notHighlighted` had references to stuff allocated by SDL, and the destructor has SDL deallocate that stuff, and the copy constructor of `text` did not make proper clones of these items, the references pointed by `buttonText` will be no longer valid.

To avoid that, you have a couple of options:

- Make sure that `text` creates appropriate copies of referenced SDL objects when copy-constructed.
- Use raw pointers and make sure you know when you should delete the text. (This is doable but requires great care to avoid memory leaks.)

  ```
  string textContent;
  text* buttonText;
  text* highlighted_buttonText;

  //Constructor
  buttonObj(string tex, text* notHighlighted, text* highlighted) : 
    textContent( tex ), 
    buttonBase( img ), 
    buttonText( notHighlighted ), 
    highlighted_buttonBase( hI ), 
    highlighted_buttonText( highlighted )
  {}
  ```
- Use shared pointers so that the object is properly deleted when no longer in use. (This is one of the favoured methods.)

  ```
  string textContent;
  std::shared_ptr<text> buttonText;
  std::shared_ptr<text> highlighted_buttonText;

  //Constructor
  buttonObj(string tex, std::shared_ptr<text> notHighlighted, std::shared_ptr<text> highlighted) : 
    textContent( tex ), 
    buttonBase( img ), 
    buttonText( notHighlighted ), 
    highlighted_buttonBase( hI ), 
    highlighted_buttonText( highlighted )
  {}
  ```

---

> I see that the texts are constructed and then destructed

Instead of just spamming the console with "text::ctor" and "text::dtor" when constructed and destructed, also output the address of the object (i.e. the `this` pointer) you'll see a bit more *what object* is actually being constructed and destructed.

And as always, even if outputing data to the console is one of the best way to debug, a good step-by-step debugger is very nice to have and use in such cases.

Comment: Hmmmm.. okay, I'm going to go with the shared_ptr method. So I have other functions within the "text" class, for example text::draw(). When I changed text to shared_ptr<text> in the manner you described, these functions no longer worked. (class "std::shared_ptr<text>" has no member "draw") How do I keep the "text" functions working, but still use this method? Thanks so much!

Comment: @EyesightTechnology perhaps editing the question and adding the core parts of the class `text`, and how the `buttonObj` are used would help give you a better answer on this.

Comment: buttonObj has another function, which simply does buttonText.draw(). The "draw()" function is a member of the text class. However, the compiler seems to make a distinction between "shared_ptr<text>" and just regular "text", because it claims that "draw()" is not a function in the "shared_ptr<text>" class. "draw()" is a function of the "text" class, but I guess not a function of "shared_ptr<text>". See above comment for exact error message.

Comment: Yes, you have to treat shared_ptr<text> as a pointer, so you have to use `buttonText->draw()` instead of `buttonText.draw()`.

Comment: Ah yes! Of course! So now I'm trying to pass a "text" into a new "buttonObj" obviously by passing it into the constructor. I realize that this isn't working because I must now pass a "shared_ptr<text>" into the constuctor instead of just a normal "text" But, this doesn't work either, because I don't know how to construct the "shared_ptr<text>" pointer... I need to construct it beforehand, like so: `shared_ptr<text> textptr(color2); buttonObj button(textptr);`

Comment: It's a pointer, you need to allocate it dynamically with `new`, like such: `shared_ptr<text> textptr = std::make_shared<text>(color2);`.

Comment: Ok. **I'll test _this_ method tomorrow** and get back to you. In the meantime, this whole thing seems a little cumbersome. As in, creating a shared_ptr<text> and deleting it later. Is there any easier/less complex way to do this? Why is using your second method with "raw pointers" more difficult, in terms of avoiding memory leaks? How would I go about doing that cleanly and safely?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71899/discussion-between-alexandre-vaillancourt-and-eyesight-technology).